# mongoose pre update not firing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have follow the directions in mongoose [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes)

```
PostSchema.pre('update', function() {
    console.log('pre update');
    console.log(this);
});
```

it is not firing this middleware. Am I missing something here?

I have added `next` so it looks exactly like my pre save, however that still does nothing.

Comment: also, aspect with using .exec() method can affect to the behaviour of the hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't define this after `mongoose.model()` has been called. Please also take note that `findOneAndUpdate` / upserts or updates won't trigger this hook. Another reason why it wouldn't execute is that validation fails. Therefore you would need to setup a `pre('validate')` hoke

Comment: You're correct it was the `findOneAndUpdate` a little confusing though.

Comment: `pre('validate')` does _not_ fire for `update` operations (see [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6573)). Use `save` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the `await` keyword before your promise.